# How to know the row from the whole tableview selected in a search of my Search Display Controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

As the title says, in my code, when I search in my app happens this in a simple way:

```
stations = [barcelona, madrid, valencia, badajoz]
```

when I type "ba" it shows:

```
mysearch = [barcelona, badajoz]
```

I want to select badajoz, so the program returns that row is position 1, when in stations is position number 3.

Any idea?

PD: Code related to search

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate 
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    self.searchResults = [self.allItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController delegate methods
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString 
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text] 
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
    return YES;
}
```

EDIT: I edited my code using the answer below
    - (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath{
        NSLog(@"Pushing...");
        NSUInteger row = [indexPath row]; //older code before search view

```
    //index from the search
    id searchResult = [searchResults objectAtIndex:row];
    int indexForResult = [ListaEstaciones indexOfObject:searchResult];
    //more stuff
```

EDIT:
Now it works for this cases: with the list with all elements it searches well, when I start to search it works well to, the problem is that when stop searching and I select a row of the list of all elements it still uses de index of the list of searched items before, this happens because in this code I change the searching boolean variable to YES:

```
    - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText 
                             scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate 
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    self.searchResults = [self.allItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    searching = YES;
```

But I don't know where to change searching value to NO when I return to the list of all values. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.
EDIT 2: Solved with this website http://engineeringtheworld.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/detecting-when-clear-is-clicked-in-uisearchbar-x-button/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an object you can find out its index in an array. Using your example at the top:

```
id searchResult = [mysearch objectAtIndex:1];
int indexForResult = [stations indexOfObject:searchResult];
```

You won't want to process these two statements if you didn't do a search as they don't make sense. To stop them getting processed will require you put them inside an if statement and check if you have done a search or not.

After looking at your error it would seem that you have an array with 1160 Objects in it and your code is asking for object 2147483647. This obviously doesn't exist and so the code crashes. Why you get this error I'm not totally sure and is something only you can really answer. Use breakpoints and the debugger to find out where the code is going wrong.

Comment: This stuff works, only problem is when i select a row without having searched anything, this makes error, here is my piece of code where I save the row  
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row]; //chosen row, made before I put a search controller  
    //if i have browsed anything  
    id searchResult = [searchResults objectAtIndex:row];  
    int indexForResult = [ListaEstaciones indexOfObject:searchResult];   Any suggestion?

Comment: What error does it give? Where is this code going? If you have a long response like this it may be best to edit your question :)

Comment: The problem is simple, when I select a row without searching, the line of the code that does:  id searchresult = [searchResults objectAtIndex: row];  is an error, because the is not any searchresult. Any suggestion of how to detect if i have searched or not or other solution? Thanks a lot for you time spent in this question.

Comment: Thats right. I would make an instance variable called searching. set `searching = YES` when the user starts searching. then check it when processing a tap :)

Comment: Where should I declare searching? Inside shouldReloadTableForSearchScope, shouldReloadTableForSearchString, filterContentForSearchText functions? If I declare on them the variable will not be visible to didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: declare it in your `@interface`

Comment: Solved! Thanks a lot, I edited the main thread of this topic with the answer ;)